# copying data from text file to the another

Tags: c, text, copying

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
;3;untyped;31.1948;29.917 
;3;untyped;31.195;29.9168 
;3;untyped;31.195;3;29.9167 
;3;untyped;31.1955;29.9166
```

I want to copy it to another text file so that looks like this:

```
number_of_lines lat1 long1 t1 lat2 long2 t2 lat3 long3 t3.....
```

where t begins at 1 and increments by 1 each time.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{   
    FILE *file2 = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    int NOL=1;
    char ch;
    FILE *file1 = fopen("in.txt", "r");     
    while((ch=fgetc(file1))!=EOF)                  //loop to find out how many lines are in the text file
    {
        if (ch=='\n') { NOL++; }
    }
    printf("number of lines = %d \n",NOL);
    fclose(file1);

    char line[100];
    int inc = 1;
    FILE *file3 = fopen("in.txt", "r"); 
    fprintf(file2,"%d ",NOL);
    for(int i=0;i<NOL;i++)
    {
        fscanf(file3,"%s\n",line);       
        char *trash1 = strtok(line, ";");      //ignoring the first part
        printf("%s\n",trash1);

        char *trash2 = strtok(NULL, ";");        //ignoring the second part
        printf("%s\n",trash2);

        char *lat = strtok(NULL, ";");
        float lat_f = atof(lat);                //storing the lat
        printf("%s\n",lat); 

        char *lon = strtok(NULL, ";");
        float lon_f = atof(lon);             //storing the long
        printf("%s\n",lon); 

        fprintf(file2,"%f %f %d ",lat_f,lon_f,inc);    //printing the values to the output text file
        inc++;
    }
    fclose (file3); 
    fclose (file2);     
}
```

When i run my code, some of the copied values aren't copied correctly, as seen below

```
4 31.194799 29.917000 1 31.195000 29.916800 2 31.195000 **3.000000** 3 31.195499 29.916599 4
```

Why does that happen? Is there something wrong with the code? How can I fix it please.

Comment: please allways check the result of fopen()

Comment: Works as expected here. Is the supplemental `3;` in the input file a typo ?

Comment: I agree with @MichaelWalz, the extra 3; is the problem.  You may want to check that each line has the correct number of values ... if not, you could handle be ignoring or flagging the row as invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your third line has an optional `;`, so the output is correct

Answer (score 1):

In your example 4 lines, line 3 contains additional data in field 4 `3;` so that's where your "unexpected" `3` is coming from.

Comment: Yeah it was a typo :S. Really sorry for this